# Fre jqGrid 4.8.0 - Changing the modal colors

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I'm familiar wit the trick to overwrite the modal behavior:

```
$.extend($.jgrid, {
showModal : function(h) {
    h.w.show("blind");
},
closeModal : function(h) {
    h.w.hide("blind").attr("aria-hidden", "true");
    if(h.o) {h.o.remove();}
}
});
```

I'm also looking for a way to change the color of that same modal header.  (I don't want to change the color for the entire .ui-widget-header, just for that particular modal window). Can I achieve that using  "h.w.css" of some kind?

This is how how open this modal:

```
$(nameOfGrid).jqGrid('searchGrid', {
                multipleSearch:true,
                showQuery: true,
                multipleGroup:true,
                caption: "Advanced Search",
                sFilter: "afilters",
                Find: "Apply",
                Reset: "Reset & Close",
                closeAfterReset: true,
                closeAfterSearch: false,
                searchOnEnter: true,
                width:'auto',
                recreateForm: true,
                recreateFilter: false,
                errorcheck: true,
                overlay:false,
```

Thanks,

Comment: Which modal dialog you mean? How the modal will be created? Do you use just Add/Edit/Delete dialogs and want to modify someone or you create the dialog **manually** using direct call of `createModal` or `info_dialog`? I'm modifying now the code of free jqGrid to allow to customize the classes used in different elements of jqGrid. I will modify the code of `createModal`, `info_dialog`, `viewModal`, `hideModal` very soon. If you would provide *an example* of what you do I could make the changes so that it would easy for you.

Comment: Thanks, I added the example to the question body.

Comment: Thanks, but what you want exactly to change in the `caption` of the Searching Dialog? Do you want to change the color of the text `"Advanced Search"`? You can use any HTML fragment as the value of `caption`. For example `caption: "<span style='color:red'>Advanced Search</span>"` will set red text and `caption: "<span style='background-color:red'>Advanced Search</span>"` will change the background color of the header. Could you make your example full and to describe **which changes exactly you want to do in the modal header?**

Comment: Thanks, I need to change the color of the entire ui-widget-header.  So not just the background of the caption itself, but the all header of the modal window.

Comment: Sorry, but it's still not full understand what you want. If you want to change the entire header of the searching dialog that you can add your custom class to the header *after* the call of `searchGrid`. Something like `$(nameOfGrid).jqGrid('searchGrid', {...}); $("#searchhdfbox_" + $.jgrid.jqID($grid[0].id)).addClass("ui-state-error");` where `$grid` is `$(nameOfGrid)`.

Comment: You are welcome! I posted the last suggesting as the answer. Probably it will help other readers too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add additional class to the header **after** the modal dialog is created. The id of the header of Searching dialog will be constructed from the prefix `searchhdfbox_` and the grid id. So you can do for example the following

```
var $grid = $(nameOfGrid);

// create the Searching Dialog
$grid.jqGrid('searchGrid', {...});

// add the class "ui-state-error" to the dialog header
$("#searchhdfbox_" + $.jgrid.jqID($grid[0].id)).addClass("ui-state-error");
```